# Wordpress Featured Image Not Displaying

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show a small version of the featured image as a post thumbnail on my main page (index.php). For this I am implementing it as the background-image of a div. Unfortunately the code (which had been working before) has stopped working now and I cannot find a reason why. I have been looking everywhere for a solution, but I just cant figure it out.
I am using the following code but unfortunately it doesnt return anything:

```
<?php $post_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_to_use->ID);
if ($post_image_id) {
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_image_id, 'post-thumbnail', false);
if ($thumbnail) (string)$thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];
} ?>

<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
<div class="post_image_crop" style="background: url('<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>')">
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can have a look at it here: [oliverprenzel.com](http://oliverprenzel.com)

The weird thing is, I have done exactly the same thing on my single.php where it still does work.

```
<?php $post_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_to_use->ID);
if ($post_image_id) {
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_image_id, 'post-thumbnail', false);
if ($thumbnail) (string)$thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];
} ?>

<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
<div class="post_image_bg" style="background: url('<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>'); background-size: 100% !important;">
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can have a look at it working here: [oliverprenzel.com/headmagazine/](http://oliverprenzel.com/headmagazine/)

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this?

Edit for Claudiu:
This is the loop I am trying to get the image in:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<?php $post_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
    if ($post_image_id) {
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_image_id, 'post-thumbnail', false);
        if ($thumbnail) (string)$thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];
    } ?>
<!-- post loop prev -->
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <div class="post_frame">
        <div class="post_image_crop" style="background: url('<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>')">
        </div>
        <div class="prev_det">
            <div class="prev_det_center">
                <h1>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h1>
                <p><?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prev_det_fold"></div>
    </div>
</a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get each posts thumbnail, then you need to move

```
<?php $post_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
    if ($post_image_id) {
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_image_id, 'post-thumbnail', false);
        if ($thumbnail) (string)$thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];
    } ?>
```

inside the loop and change it to:

```
<?php $post_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() );
    if ($post_image_id) {
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_image_id, 'post-thumbnail', false);
        if ($thumbnail) (string)$thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];
    } ?>
```

My guess is that `$post_image_id` is returning null because you don't have a featured image for your home page and even if you had, the same image will be displayed for each post.

Comment: Great, thank you, changing it to get_the_ID() and moving it into the loop made it work.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have a strong suspicion that in your first line    `$post_to_use->ID` returns null. When the argument in get_post_thumbnail_id() returns null then the current post id is used by default. This is why it is working in `single.php`, because there you have a post loaded.

On frontpage you don't. So you have to check which post id you want, manually enter it or do a loop.

Try replacing `get_post_thumbnail_id($post_to_use->ID)` with `get_post_thumbnail_id(5)` where 5 is the post id that you want.

Comment: I have changed what you suggested and it displayed the image for every post. However replacing the id with anything else than a number (ie $post_id) does return nothing again. 
Is there a way to get this to work inside the post loop?
I have edited my post above and pasted the full code I am using for the loop.

Comment: I should clarify it obviously showed just the same image for every post.